# Input issues with password generator

Tags: python

i wrote a simple password generator but am having trouble with the inputs.

when running password(10) for example, it runs perfectly but when i request for input, it doesn't seem to register the input as an integer.

any advice?

```
import random
def password(x):
    pw = str()
    characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqratuvwxyz" + "0123456789" + "!@#$%^&*"
    for i in range(x):
        pw = pw + random.choice(characters)
    return pw

x1 = input("How many characters would you like your password to have? ")

while x1 != int():
    print("Please key in an Integer")
    x1 = input("How many characters would you like your password to have? ")

password(x1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers)

Comment: `x1 != int()` is not how you check if a variable is an int.

Answer (score 1):

`input()` will always return a string, even if it's a string of a number.

You'll need to convert it to an `int` with the `int()` function. The code below also catches when the input can't be converted to an `int`. We wrap it in a `while` loop so as long as the user doesn't input a `str` that can be converted to an `int` it keeps asking.

```
valid = False
while not valid:
    try:
        x1 = int(x1)
        valid = True
    except ValueError:
        print('not an int')
```

Also trying to see if something is an `int` with the statement `x1 == int()` isn't the right way to do it. `int()` will just return 0. Instead use `isinstance()` like this:

```
if isinstance(your_var, int):
    <your code>
```

Of course, that's irrelevant because of the fact that `input()` will always return a string.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3 `input()` returns a string like python 2's `raw_input()` to read integers just do `int(input('some question'))`